# Unknown WiFi Network

Tags: network, wifi

For background, I am being sued by unethical people who would do anything. I live in a rural area and in the network list on my phone and laptop, no neighboring networks appear. Only our own plus our Guest. Recently, a network appeared named Test. Sometimes late at night my phone will be logged on to this network though I didn’t do it. When I try to log on to it, a password is required and I can’t do so. How can I find out what is going on? I have an iPhone and MacBook. It does not appear that my laptop has ever connected to this network. Here is what I see on my phone. (Centurylink and Russell both belong to me)
[image]

Comment: Many peripherals (e.g. printers, scanners, etc.) now include built-in wifi access points nowadays.  The same is true for many appliances with 'IoT' functionality (e.g. refrigerators, thermostats, etc.).  It's possible that the access point that you are seeing could be built-in to one of these devices.  Did you buy any new peripherals or appliances recently?

Answer (score 1):

There are wifi AP locator apps that allow you to use your phone to physically locate wifi access points. You can use one of these to hunt down the physical location of the network to determine if it is a local device (your fridge) or if someone added a new wifi network AP around your house.

It is most likely a new device you have purchased with a poor network name.